# Sliding a UIView down and then back up

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have a UIView that is will slide down on button tap and then slide back up on another button tap. It slides down perfectly, but when I try to hit the contract button, I can't click it, but it does click a collection view cell that is underneath the view. I can't figure out why it slides down properly but it doesn't function how I expect. Thanks a lot!

```
@IBAction func onExpandButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
      let xPosition = expandingView.frame.origin.x

      //View will slide to 40 px higher bottom of the screen
      let yPosition = expandingView.frame.maxY - 40

      let height = expandingView.frame.size.height
      let width = expandingView.frame.size.width

      UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {

         self.expandingView.frame = CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, height, width)
         self.expandButton.hidden = true
         self.contractButton.hidden = false
      })
   }

   @IBAction func onContractButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

      let xPosition = expandingView.frame.origin.x
      let yPosition = expandingView.frame.origin.y

      let height = expandingView.frame.size.height
      let width = expandingView.frame.size.width

      UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {

         self.expandingView.frame = CGRectMake(xPosition, yPosition, height, width)
         self.expandButton.hidden = false
         self.contractButton.hidden = true
      })
   }
```

Comment: Is the button that isn't working outside the bounds of it's parent view?  This will cause hit testing to fail in the way you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it's because the view has slid *over* the button. So try to use the following inside the button action that will slide over the non-working button:

```
self.view.bringSubViewToFront(buttonName)
```

If you put an NSLog inside your button Action, it can help determine if the function is being called.